# (would+have+pp) or simple past

Tags: grammar

This paragraph is on an articular of a newspaper:

> Thai officials arrested the five-man crew on Friday after seizing the large cargo craft at Bangkok’s military airport, where the crew had landed to refuel. It was unclear why the crew **would have chosen** a close American ally for a refueling stop, rather than neighboring Myanmar, which has deep business and political ties to North Korea.

--taken from The New York Times

I dont know what is the difference between:

1.It was unclear why the crew **would have chosen** a close American ally for a refueling stop (would+have+pp)

2.It was unclear why the crew **chose** a close American ally for a refueling stop (the simple past)

Answer (score 1):

1. It was unclear why the crew would have chosen a close American ally for a refueling stop ----- here Writer is contemplating about the incident.
2. It was unclear why the crew chose a close American ally for a refueling stop--- here writer is providing information about what has happened to readers. there is no attempt of finding the reasons.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).